# How can I add a printer which becomes available to the default user created using cubic

Tags: xubuntu, printing

Since systemback wouldn't allow me to create an ISO (button remains grayed out!), I have given cubic a try. It works fine. I could add all packages etc. There are only two points, which elude me:

1. Can't add a printer, so that the user needs no further action to access his printer
2. can't enable gufw in chroot window

All suggestions appreciated.

Comment: For those that are not aware, [Cubic](https://github.com/PJ-Singh-001/Cubic/wiki) is software that allows you to install packages and make other changes to the Live ISO used to install Ubuntu. See the [Cubic Wiki](https://github.com/PJ-Singh-001/Cubic/wiki) for more information. Users can customize their ISO before installing, so they do not need to make changes after installing Ubuntu. This is really useful when you need to install Ubuntu with exactly the same packages, settings, configurations on multiple computers.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. As said, I could navigate through cubic and using the virtual terminal provided, also install packages and even create a user. Somehow, I can't create a user profile in this terminal which can be put in /etc/skel  and which contains the settings such as for gufw and the printer. Is there any description of that process somewhere? How can I set up a printer and gufw in this terminal and where are the files of that set-up to be found, so as to put copies of the same in the structure for sqhfs. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is a way pointed out by [link](https://answers.launchpad.net/cubic/+question/702927). 
Could someone please point out to me, where gufw puts its settings. I can't locate them in either /home  or in /root  folder's  .config subfolder. Bleachbit settings have been successfully incorporated in the cubic virtual terminal though.